# executing a code when a user exits website in Joomla 2.5

Tags: events, joomla, web, joomla2.5

I'm new with Joomla 2.5.

I want to delete a row from a userdefined table when a user closes the website. I don't know where to find the code which executes when a person exits Joomla web application.

In asp.net, it is pretty easy as u need to extend `OnApplicationExit()` event handler. I couldn't find a similar event in Joomla 2.5. Is it even possible to do that in joomla 2.5?

Alternatively, I can also delete a row from table when a user session is timed out, but I don't know how to do that. Please, provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a system or user plugin, the event you're looking for is `onUserLogout`

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User